# Change CSS style according to URL

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have looked everywhere, but couldn't found a simple solution.

CSS would be best.

Basically I want to change the link css style according to the URL.

So, let's say, there are three menu items:

HOME (https://www.example.com)

PRODUCTS (https://www.example.com/products)

SERVICES (https://www.example.com/services)

I want that, when a visitor is ON https://www.example.com, the HOME link would be Blue.

All other - black.

When on /products, then PRODUCTS would be in blue and all others (HOME and SERVICES) in black.

Example below:

[image]

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

P.S. not on hover, but when a visitor is on the specific URL.

Comment: you probably want to add a class attribute to the relevant elements, and in your CSS stylesheet add rules to make the menu items with that class look the way you want. It's not clear how you are generating the HTML for each page, whether they are hard-coded files or generated by some server-side framework, so it's hard to give more detail than that.

Comment: it's a Wordpress blog

Comment: You probably mean hover?

Comment: No. Not on hover, when a person is on the specific URL.

Comment: You mean when `document.location === url` ?

Comment: yes. that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Wordpress' menu system.

In that case, the active menu item will automatically be marked with class `current-menu-item`

Then you'll be able to style it differently than others with css

Detailed information on how to declare a custom menu area in your WordPress theme
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-navigation-menus-in-wordpress-3-0-themes/

Comment: hey, it's useful. thanks. But I'm using my own custom menu (not a nav_bar) in my widget with icons in front of the text. Similar to the twitter example above.

So I need for (ico) + Text to change the color.

Not sure if a default Wordpress nav-bar can do that.

Comment: You can render pretty much anything with wordpress menu. Just dig into the function or find a plug-in that helps you customize your menu's looks. If you really want to do your own thing then the way to go is the same: just add a special class to selected menu item on server side depending on visited url